# Compiler differences in template expansion with default member value and incomplete type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

There appears to be a difference in when templates are expanded for class members that have default initializers between MSVC and Clang, which can sometimes lead to code that compiles successfully in MSVC but fails in Clang.

The problem code in question was fairly complex and spread across multiple files, but I think the following toy example shows the same discrepancy:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class Impl;

class A {
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> ptr = nullptr;
public:
  A();
  ~A();
};

int main() {}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3s5Drh

As seen in the compiler explorer, Clang gives an error for this code. If the `= nullptr` is removed, both compilers will run without errors.

Obviously this code won't do anything and even if it did, the `= nullptr` would not be necessary anyway. I am curious though, as to whether there is anything in the standard that says whether one or other of these compilers is correct in this case?

Comment: I would've guessed that it has something to do with the initialization (semantically) employing a temporary which needs cleanup which calls the deleter which is the only part of `unique_ptr` that [requires](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#dltr.dflt-4) `Impl` to be a complete type, but [the same happens](https://godbolt.org/z/Eo-b8f) in newer C++ versions where there is no temporary (look at the ASTs)... gcc agrees on clang's complaints though: https://godbolt.org/z/vdVdb9

Comment: Same error with gcc [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8731d8a9007a8c42), but, for me, msvc seems correct (even if both gcc/clang agree).

Comment: My two cents. [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) is performed. It states 

"*appropriate constructor (move or copy) is required to be accessible even though it's not used. (until C++17)*"

Therefore, in that case, copy/move template instantiation will require the destructor (because that how `std::unique_ptr` works).
However, I cannot provide an an answer because `-std=c++17` gives the same error (it shouldn't)

Comment: @BiagioFesta: No code is generated, we just have `A` definition. No methods are defined just declared (even implicitly) (ignoring `<memory>` :-) ).

Comment: class `Impl` needs to be a complete type.  I'm surprised MSVC didn't catch this.

Comment: @PaulSanders No. It doesn't. At least it's not evident to me why.

Comment: Interestingly, adding a definition of `Impl` _after_ everything fixes the issue... So two-phase is not the culprit (not that it would make sense), and _something_ is happening at the end of the file in gcc and clang, but I don't know what.

Comment: Yeah, my gut feeling was that it shouldn't be trying to do anything at this point and should therefore compile, but I don't know whether there are rules about how default member values should be implemented that would effectively force some inlining here?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Nice catch. At this point, I think the issue it's strictly related how the *member values* is implemented by the compiler.

Comment: @PaulSanders Why? Note that the standard explicitly allows incomplete template parameters both for [`unique_ptr`](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#4) and its [`default_delete`](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#dltr.general-2). As long as `Impl` is a complete type when the `operator()(T*)` of the `default_delete` is generated (which would normally be in the destructor _definition_ of `A`), everything should be good.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Well, we have `/opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/memory:2334:19: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'Impl'`, for whatever reason, see https://wandbox.org/permlink/1ibLAwHfDhf14q2p

Comment: @PaulSanders a compiler can have bugs. Indeed here we have different behaviors for three different compilers. In general, the standard allows *incomplete types* for `std::unique_ptr` until the destructor is not required.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, that's what the question is about. This is puzzling because, as mentioned, [complete types are not usually required](https://godbolt.org/z/evKSBL) as long as your code doesn't _itself_ create or destroy the respective `unique_ptr` instances. And this is clearly the intent of the standard (partially so that `unique_ptr` is on-par with evil owning raw pointers regarding compile-time encapsulation) - it literally [says so](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#4.sentence-3).

Comment: This is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85552 and https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39363

Comment: @MaxLanghof I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several bugs involved here, see https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39363#c8

> So: two bugs in GCC (though they might be the same thing), one bug in Clang's C++17 support, one bug in libstdc++, and no bugs in libc++. Retargeting this as a Clang bug. :)

And the libstdc++ was actually a defect in the standard that got inadvertently fixed by https://wg21.link/lwg2081 (see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87704 for more details).

I think the program is actually invalid in C++14 mode, because the default member initializer uses copy-initialization, so a temporary gets created and then moved-from, and then the temporary destroyed. Destroying the temporary means the destructor should be instantiated, which requires a complete type. In C++17 mode guaranteed copy elision means there is no temporary, and so no destructor instantiation, and the code should be valid. But GCC and Clang both do the wrong thing, even in C++17 mode.

If you use direct-list-initialization instead of copy-initialization then it works with Clang:

```
std::unique_ptr<Impl> ptr{nullptr};
```

And this also works:

```
std::unique_ptr<Impl> ptr{};
```

And the equivalent:

```
std::unique_ptr<Impl> ptr = {};
```

And just not providing an initializer at all also works, and works with GCC too:

```
std::unique_ptr<Impl> ptr;
```

Comment: The [comment](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39363#c8) by Richard Smith explains the reasoning in more detail, including the concept of "potentially invoked" which is relevant here.

Comment: "*because the default member initializer uses copy-initialization*". Well, I thought the same. However, the place where all should happen is `A::A()` which is defined into another TU. So do we really need to expect an error in the class definition (even if the constructor will be defined into another TU)?

Comment: There are compiler bugs, so what happens isn't what you expect.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this program would be invalid in C++14 mode because, as mentioned above, I thought the copy initialisation would only happen in the definition of the constructor which doesn't exist here. I am marking it as answered though, because the bug reports do explain the compiler differences that I asked about.